# Prefetch DNS using AdGuard Home

Tags: networking, dns, cache, openwrt, adblock

Is it possible to configure AdGuard Home to preemptively cache popular DNS records, similar to [unbound's prefetch option](https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/manpages/unbound.conf.html#unbound-conf-prefetch)?

> prefetch: 
> If yes, message cache elements are prefetched before they expire to keep the cache up to date. Turning it on gives about 10 percent more traffic and load on the machine, but popular items do not expire from the cache.
> Default: no

I'm on a relatively high latency connection and don't want to introduce more latency by using [`unbound`](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/). The only similar setting I could find in AdGuard Home is [`cache_optimistic`](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdGuardHome/wiki/Configuration#configuration-file), but that appears to be a little different:

> `cache_optimistic` (since v0.107.0) — Make AdGuard Home respond from the cache even when the entries are expired and also try to refresh them. Before v0.108.0-b.5 the TTL for such responses is 60 seconds and since v0.108.0-b.5 it's 10 seconds.

I'm interested in `unbound`'s prefetch approach: increased traffic and cache size for top 10% or so records, but always up-to-date. Is there a way to implement this with AdGuard Home, or AdGuard Home and `dnsmasq`?

Am running [AdGuard Home on OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/dns/adguard-home).

Comment: Have you considered using hosts files to block domain lookups at the hosts level?  (Adaway uses these, and there are quite a lot of lists available - searching "adaway host lists" may help find these.   You would be able to use DNSMasq with hosts to do blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Prefetching of cached DNS records that are close to expiring is not implemented in AdGuard Home.

There an open [issue requesting this feature](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdGuardHome/issues/1259) in the official repo, but there has been no work on it for a long time.